# Install4j Java version warning

Tags: install4j

Our installer build (using install4j 5.1.15) has started generating warnings (about 1500 per media file) which I think might be related to the fact that we have upgraded our project to Java 8. Is there a way to solve this? Should we be concerned about this message? Can it cause any problems? I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695950/is-it-possible-to-generate-with-java-8-and-install4j-5-1-5-a-warning-free-instal) but it doesn't explain if it can cause problem, or if there's a way to resolve the issue (e.g.: upgrading to a newer version of install4j)

```
[INFO] [warning] major version should be between 45 and 51 for JDK <= 1.7
```

Answer (score 3):

install4j 5 cannot read Java class file with -target 1.8. install4j checks your code for usages of the install4j API so that the shrinked runtime file includes all required classes. The warning messages mean that install4j cannot perform this task. You can switch off runtime shrinking to avoid this problem on the "General Settings->Media File Options" step.

Also, this problem goes away when using install4j 6.

Comment: Thank you Ingo for getting back to me. I assume then that when the shrinking library is unable to analyse the Java 8 classes it bails out, meaning the resulting installer is not "damaged" at all, it's just not shrunk. Is that correct?

Comment: If you use install4j API in your code, it might be shrunk too much. If you do not use the API, then you should be fine.